# How can I Setup and Manage Several SQL Server Scripts to use in VB.NET?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a quick question.  What is the best way to setup manage several SQL Server queries?  I am comfortable with the concept below.

```vb
Dim strtdate As String
Dim enddate As String

strtdate = DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy")
enddate = DateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("mm/dd/yyy")
'MsgBox(strtdate)

Using con As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    Using cmd As SqlCommand = con.CreateCommand()
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE AsOfDate BETWEEN @noticestartdate END @noticeenddate"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@noticestartdate", strtdate)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@noticeenddate", enddate)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            Using dt As New DataTable()
                sda.Fill(dt)
                DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

The thing is, I want to be able to create a couple dozen queries somewhat similar to the one above, but each will be slightly different.  I can create all the SQL scripts just fine.  I am just not sure how to store, and retrieve, all the queries that I will need to use.  I definitely don't want to hard code all of these, and pass in dates from a DateTime Picker.  I just want to understand how to create a library of SQL statements, and make everything fairly easy to maintain.  I was thinking of storing query names in a table, along with the SQL that I need to execute, but I am not sure this will work.  Should I create a couple dozen SProcs, and call each from some kind of control?  That seems like overkill.  I'm just trying to figure out the best way to setup and maintain this process.

My Form looks like this:

[image]

My SQL Server table looks like this.

[image]

Basically...I was thinking of feeling the 'ReportName' into the ListBox
 and when a user selects a report, such as 'Sum_Of_Deal_Balance_By_Month', I was hoping to fire off the relevant SQL: `declare @startDate datetime declare @endDate datetime declare @Name varchar(MAX) SELECT * FROM (SELECT Contact_ID, TB_Line, Deal_Balance, DATENAME(Month,[AsOfDate]) AS TheDate  FROM [TBL_FR2052A_OperationalDepositTag_HIST] Where [AsOfDate] >= @startDate and [AsOfDate] <= @endDate) AS P PIVOT (SUM(DEAL_BALANCE) FOR TheDate in (January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December)) AS PV;`

That would be passed into Excel and a small chart is created in Excel.  I have working code samples that do all the Excel stuff.  I'm just not sure of the best way to let a user create Excel reports.  I am toying with the ListBox idea, but maybe there is a better, and easier, way to do this.  I'm certainly open to feedback here!  Thanks!

Comment: SQL code is just text, so you can store a SQL query anywhere you can store text. Where is best for your particular situation is up to you.

Comment: What are the requirements? What problems do you have with the most simplest approach (storing as text files). Wrapping SQL in an app, storing in a table etc. etc. seems to be completely overcomplicating the situation. You can parameterise scripts by definining variables at the top, i.e. `DECLARE @Date DATETIME`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A stored procedure is probably the best approach for externalizing the SQL, but it doesn't simplify deployment.  Externalizing ad-hoc SQL doesn't buy you anything in performance and should only be used if your design really needs it.  It is a deployment and security headache.

A simple approach for implementing it internally is to create a class of shared functions that caches and return a command object for each SQL call you need.  I just keep the SQL in code.  Also check out the Command.Prepare function.  It can improve performance a lot if you are calling queries in loops and can't use sprocs.

Comment: Glenn, so you keep everything in code, like I illustrated?  Nick, I tried to store the name of the query in one field of a table, and all SQL in another field in the same table, but I couldn't pull the SQL out of the second field.  I could only get the first field, the name.  Any idea how to get the second field based on the first field?

Comment: Yes, I keep it in code, similar to your example.  What is the benefit of moving your SQL queries into a table?  It really is another layer of work and maintenance and should be justified....  Your second question to Nick is concerning me.  You are able to write SQL, but don't know how to select a row based on a field?   You should test all your SQL in SSMS before running it in code.   Try something like this:  `SELECT query FROM queries WHERE queryname = 'RecordsByDate1'`

Comment: Yes, yes, yes, that's child's stuff.  I'm trying to make all this work in VB.  I figured I would use a ListBox to display records, and then run a SQL script, based on whatever record a user chooses.  That's what I am trying to figure out.  Maybe I am doing this the wrong way.  It shouldn't be very hard.  I need to re-think my approach to this problem.

Comment: What you describe is doable (even if I don't agree with the approach. :) ) Could you post the code you are trying now?

Comment: Glenn, I just updated my original post.  I added a couple of screen shots and a little more dimension around what I'm trying to achieve.  This doesn't have to be a professional thing.  It's just a small tool to allow my colleagues to interact with some data sets that we use on a monthly basis.

Comment: @ryguy72 As Glenn suggested. A "Stored Procedure" is what you are looking for. Instead of storing your code as text in a table, it is stored in the database as it's own self-contained object. You may want to look into SSDT as a project to add to your solution. This will help you maintain the procedures in Visual Studio and you won't have to flip back and forth between SQL and VS. Also helps with version control, etc. etc. Your CommandType then becomes .StoredProcedure and you pass the name of the procedure to the SqlCommand instead of a string.

Comment: Ok!  Got it!!  Thanks everyone!!